# Empirical Data on Refactoring?

Tags: refactoring

Are there any empirical studies that show the impact of refactoring (or lack of refactoring) on a development team's productivity?

(NOTE: I'm only looking for empirical data--From my own experience, I personally know that refactoring works, but I was wondering if there was some hard data to back that claim).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Trends in Java code changes: the key to identiﬁcation of
refactorings?](https://web.archive.org/web/20170808172102/http://faculty.salisbury.edu/~xswang/Research/Papers/SERelated/Refactor/p45-counsell.pdf)

[A Case Study on the Impact of Refactoring on Quality and Productivity in an Agile Team](http://www.springerlink.com/content/v4m8pt112041587j/)

[Extracting refactoring trends from open-source software and a possible solution to the 'related refactoring' conundrum](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1141277.1141685)

[The Effectiveness of Refactoring, Based on a Compatibility Testing Taxonomy and a Dependency Graph](https://web.archive.org/web/20101028161057/http://www.computer.org:80/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/TAIC-PART.2006.33)

[And lastly](https://www.lmgtfy.app/?q=Refactoring%20Empirical%20Data)

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.springerlink.com/content/v4m8pt112041587j/) looks to have the info you seek.